Sharepoint Online, Update 2 Fields on Modification from a user
In my sharepoint online sites, we have a group of custom fields.
Now there are 2 fields i want to update, when the file is modified by some specific user,
What i want to do is that when a file is modify from any one but a specific user, i want to save the user in a custom field, and the timestamp of the update in another.
How can i get this done?
I created the custom fields, but i am looking on a way to make the field be auto filled.
Update : I need to do this with the tools i got in sharepoint online site. i Dont have access to PowerAutomate

Power Automate can create a flow that accomplishes certain tasks you specify when modifying the column values you specify. But this requires additional credentials.

can this be done withuot power automate?
